# how to do sec_to_time in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, time, milliseconds, seconds

I have a field with seconds after midnight, and I have to convert it to HH:MM:SS. MySQL has sec_to_time(), which would be perfect, but SQLite does not.

How to convert?

I feel like it's some combination of strftime or date, and some dividing by 3600, but I can't get it.

For example, I need to convert 3601 to 1:01. Or, 32405 -> 9:05.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [time()](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

```
select time(3601, 'unixepoch');
```

will give:

```
01:00:01
```